# Check if folder is empty or not php

Tags: php, file

I have to check if my folder asset/files is empty or not to show a message for create a new file or list all files in my folder.. but my folder is empty and i got the message "You got files"..

```
<?php
 /**
 * FileExist
 * check files
 * @return no
 */
public function fileExist()
{
    $open = "../asset/files";

    if (scandir($open)) {
        echo "`You got files";
        print_r(scandir($open));
    } else {
        echo "You haven't got files";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `scandir` always includes `.` and `..`.

Comment: Take a look at the entries. most likely it is the unfamous `.` and `..` entries...

Comment: yes i got `.` and `..` entries but i just want to list files likes test.txt etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get all files of the directory and check if it is empty or not. Your method didn't worked, because `scandir()` also includes `.` and `..`)

```
public function fileExist()
{
    $open = "../asset/files";

    if ($files = glob($open . "/*")) {
        echo "You got files";
        print_r($files);
    } else {
        echo "You haven't got files";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a nice day too ;)

Comment: Glob does not see hidden files. Some directories have a hidden '.htaccess' file.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you and its a easy method to check the folder is empty or not. 
First i scan the directory by using scandir() function of php and then count the scan dir. if its equal to 2 then its mean there is no file in the folder and if its greater or less than 2 then its mean there is file in the folder

$scan = scandir($dir);

```
if(count($scan)!=2){
echo 'you have files';
}

}else{
echo 'there is no file in directory';
}
```